# Converting form content to CSV file

Tags: forms, csv, registration

I have a registration form set up on a website where people have to fill in information required for an event. When the user press "Register", I receive an email with the text they input in the registration fields (e.g. name and email address). I know this is certainly not the most efficient way to do a registration form, but that's not the point. Right now, I have a `.txt` file with 80+ participants that looks like this:

```
Name: Alan Turing
Email: computer@princeton.edu
University: Princeton University
Other relevant stuff: He was good

Name: Albert Einstein
Email: emc2@princeton.edu
University: Institute for Advanced Studies at Princeton
Other relevant stuff: He was also pretty good

:
:
```

I would like convert this `.txt` file to a `.csv` file so I could open it in Excel. I want to convert each block of text to a comma-separated line. For instance, first participant would look like this after modification:

```
Alan Turing, computer@princeton.edu, Princeton University, He was good
Albert Einstein, emc2@princeton.edu, Institute for Advanced Studies in Princeton, He was also pretty good
:
:
```

I might just be able to code in Python but I was wondering if there was a shorter way of doing this (e.g. in Sublime Text maybe?) since I haven't touched any programming in the past year or so.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sublime text can easily do this for you. Just open the file in sublime, then hold MIDDLE MOUSE BUTTON and slide the cursor alongside the first character of every line (it will create a multi-select). The simple press: BACKSPACE, then COMMA. Done!

Comment: I could also provide a PHP-way of doing this, however.

Comment: @RichardRodriguez, what if I don't have a mouse with a middle button? (I don't have a mouse in fact I'm on a laptop).